# Android GCM PHP MYSQL

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm in serious need of an easy to understand tutorial on how to use GCM along with a database that is stored on server! The tutorials I have come across are so overwhelming and i just cannot deal! *sniff*

Anyone willing to help?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This site has really nice tutorial to see how GCM works with Php&Mysql. Just go step by step and read all explanations.
To use Google service, firstly, you should get an gcmid from Google, than put it in php file, and so on.

[Click Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)